# unify elements size in stackpanel

Tags: silverlight

I need help in unifying size of elements in stackpanel

```
 void MainPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var random = new Random();

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var grid = new Grid();

            var border = new Border()
                             {
                                 Height = random.Next(50, 150),
                                 Width = random.Next(50, 150),
                                 Margin = new Thickness(10),
                                 BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
                                 BorderThickness = new Thickness(1)
                             };

            grid.Children.Add(border);

            imageBoxesStackPanel.Children.Add(grid);
        }
```

var h = imageBoxesStackPanel.Children.Max(n => n.DesiredSize.Height);

what I am trying to achieve is to find max height and max width of each grid in stackpanel and apply it to all of them. The problem is that desired size is always wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do this in a custom way after a [measure/arrange pass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx#LayoutSystem_Measure_Arrange), before that the sizes won't be visible. 
After that (in the `OnLoaded` event, which you have), you can use the `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` of the grids.

In short:

```
var h = imageBoxesStackPanel.Children.Max(n => n.ActualHeight);
```

This is however bad for performance and will trigger another layout pass.

Remarks:
In WPF the best solution would be a `SharedSizeGroup` or a `UniformGrid`. This is not implemented in Silverlight, but there are people who have [implemented it](http://die-rooter.de/ITworks/archives/27-SharedSize-Grid-with-Silverlight.html).

Comment: Awesome! UniformGrid totally did what I need! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In WPF there is the `UniformGrid` to do this job, but unfortunately it's not implemented for Silverlight by default. There are several alternatives for it, e.g. [this one](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2009/01/uniform-grid/)